# Passing models to - and from - service layer

Tags: c#, architecture, soa

Supposing I have a model:

```
public class Thing
{
    public int? identifier { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    ... // arbitrary number of additional properties.
}
```

And an interface to a service layer containing two key methods:

```
public interface IThingService
{
    Thing GetThing(int id);
    Thing AddThing(Thing thing);
}
```

Now, suppose the service layer will automatically generate an `identifier` for each thing upon `AddThing`. Also suppose that it is important to expose this `identifier` to the presentation layer as it may be passed to other services.

Given that I must pass a `Thing` to `AddThing`, is this the best way of modelling `Thing`? The developer of the presentation layer may think that they can specify an `identifer`, but this will be ignored by the concrete implementation of `IThingService`. Of course, `identifier` must be public to be set by `IThingService` for `GetThing`.

Is it okay to simply *ignore* an `identifier` passed in a call to `AddThing`, or is there a better way to model this to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service should look something like this:

```
public interface IThingService
{
    Thing GetThing(int id);
    ThingCreationResponse AddThing(ThingCreationRequest request);
}
```

`ThingCreationRequest` would have all the necessary data to create a `Thing` entity. It would not have an identifier. Identifier would be returned by `AddThing`.

`AddThing` could simply return a `Thing` id, but in that case you should provide a well documented protocol to communicate errors (returning a negative value in case of a failure, or throw an exception).

Returning an instance of the `ThingCreationResponse` would provide you a better flexibility since you can return an id or a complete instance of the new `Thing`, also failure reasons could be communicated better.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if the service is operating on the same memory that the original `Thing` actually lives on.  If this service is disconnected, say on a different machine for instance, then updating the `Thing` will not affect the original instance and the `identifier` will never be returned to the calling code.

With that in mind, there are 2 possible paths: you intend for this service to always be local and operating on the same memory as the calling application, or you intend for this service to actual be or eventually become disconnected.

#### Connected

If it's connected, this interface will work fine, but you might still want to hide the setter for the identifier.  If you do, you can just make it internal and define both the service interface and the `Thing` object in a separate assembly, which will make the setter inaccessible to the presentation layer.  Well almost, you could still invoke it with reflection or other hijinks, but for typical stuff it will be inaccessible.

#### Disconnected

This interface is just broken because you cannot retrieve the identifier in any way, and it is necessary in order to retrieve the now saved item back.  Typical solutions here would return the identifier from the `AddThing` method or the entire object (new memory) if it's small enough.

Aside from all of this, immutable data items are difficult to reason about, and in either case I'd probably prefer to create a new `Thing` after calling `AddThing` anyway.

Comment: Hi Nick, I've modified my question so that `AddThing` returns a new instance of `Thing` (that's how it's actually modelled in the application anyway). So would you say that it would be appropriate to define `identifier` as `public int? identifier { get; internal set; }`? What if `IThingService` and `Thing` were defined in the same assembly, but `ActualThingService` had its own assembly?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case the correct signature for AddThing will be AddThing(string title, string description) and it will be the duty of the method to build the Thing object with the generated identifier.

Taking in consideration your last specification I would suggest making a second class,  ThingWithId having as members identifier and Thing.  The signature of AddThing would change to ThingWithId AddThing(Thing thing)

Comment: Thanks for the response - this was orignally the plan; however, `Thing` is potentially significantly more complex than just two properties - should have made this clear in the question.